# Why searchBar "textDidChange" get server request and got error and crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, search

Sorry ,I'm beginner of swift.
I have a searchBar and tableView which showing the data.
I also call the Api to server in func "textDidChange".
But when I input or delete text very quickly, my app crashed and I get error message like following row.
How can I prevent this situation?
Thanks.

> fatal error: Index out of range

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  self.subscribe = contacts.notifySubject.subscribe({ json in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}

func doSearch() {
    if let word = searchBar.text {
        if word.isEmpty == false {
            contacts.searchFriend(word)
        }
    } else {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    if searchText.isEmpty == true {

        contacts.friends.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        tableView.reloadData()
        return
    }else{

        doSearch()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if contacts.friends.isEmpty == false {
        return contacts.friends.count
    }
    return 0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    if contacts.friends.isEmpty == false {

        guard contacts.friends.count != 0 else { return UITableViewCell() } // don't prevent crash

        let cell: SearchTableViewCell = SearchTableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "SearchTableViewCell")
        let user:User = contacts.friends[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelName.text = user.name
        return cell
    }

    let cell = UITableViewCell()

    return cell
}
```

```
class Contacts:Model {

   var friends:[User] = [User]()

   func searchFriend(_ word:String) {
    if word.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    self.friends.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
    var params:[String:Any] = [String:Any]()
    params["value"] = keyword
    api.searchUser.get( params, { json in

        json.forEach({ (index,data) in

            let user = User(data)
            if user.isExist {
                self.friends.append(user)
            }
        })
        self.notifySubject.onNext(json)
    })
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are searching on server on text change means you are calling API continuously. before first request completes you are making next request. so when you got response of first request and reloading tableview same time another request completed again reload of table view called. here you removing objects from array when table view reloading was in process hence your app is crashing.
**You Should cancel previous api call before making new one.**
use NSOperation & NSOperationQueue to achieve this functionality.

Edit

here is example i am using to Search Bus Stop from server
API Call using AFNetworking

```
 func getStops(sessionManager:AFHTTPSessionManager, parameters:[AnyHashable:Any],completionHandler:@escaping (_ status:Bool, _ responseObject:Any)->()){

        if !ReachabilityManager.shared.isReachable {
            let error = WSError()
            error.errorTitle = "Network error"
            error.errorDescription = "Unable to connect, please check your internet connectivity."
            completionHandler(false,error)
            return
        }

        self.showNetworkActivity()

        if let deviceId = SSKeychain.uniqueDeviceId(){
            sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue(deviceId, forHTTPHeaderField: X_DEVICE_ID)
        }

        if let accessToken = DBManager.logged?.accessToken{
            sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue(accessToken, forHTTPHeaderField: X_ACCESS_TOKEN)
        }

        if let simulatedContextId = self.simulatedContextId {
            sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue(simulatedContextId, forHTTPHeaderField: X_SIMULATE_CONTEXT)
        }
        if let languageCode = NSLocale.current.languageCode{
            sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue(languageCode, forHTTPHeaderField: X_LOCALE_ID)
        }
        let urlPath =  WSApi.apiVersion + "stops"

        sessionManager.get(urlPath, parameters: parameters, progress: { progress in

        }, success: {[unowned self] task, responseObject in
            self.hideNetworkActivity()
            self.getCurretnContext(task: task)

            var stops = [Stop]()

            if let array = responseObject as? [[AnyHashable:Any]]{
                stops.append(contentsOf: Stop.GetSports(array: array))
            }

            completionHandler(true,stops)

            }, failure: {[unowned self] operation, err in
                self.hideNetworkActivity()
                self.getCurretnContext(task: operation)
                let error = WSError(error: err as NSError)
                error.getStatusCode(operation: operation)
                if error.isUnauthorised{
                    AppDelegate.shared.handleUnAuthorised(error: error)
                    return
                }
                completionHandler(false,error)

        })
    }
```

ViewController Implementation

```
 protocol StopSearchViewControllerDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {

    /**
     * Called when a place has been selected from the available autocomplete predictions.
     * @param viewController The |StopSearchViewController| that generated the event.
     * @param stop The |Stop| that was returned.
     */
    func viewController(_ viewController: StopSearchViewController, didAutocompleteWith stop: Stop)

    /**
     * Called when a non-retryable error occurred when retrieving autocomplete predictions or place
     * details. A non-retryable error is defined as one that is unlikely to be fixed by immediately
     * retrying the operation.
     * All other error codes are non-retryable.
     * @param viewController The |StopSearchViewController| that generated the event.
     * @param error The |WSError| that was returned.
     */
    func viewController(_ viewController: StopSearchViewController, didFailAutocompleteWithWSError error: WSError)


    /**
     * Called when the user taps the Cancel button in a |StopSearchViewController|.
     * @param viewController The |StopSearchViewController| that generated the event.
     */
    func autocompleteWasCancelled(_ viewController: StopSearchViewController)
}

class StopSearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    weak var delegate:StopSearchViewControllerDelegate?

    fileprivate var stops = [Stop]()

    fileprivate var isNavigationBarHidden = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
        self.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.isNavigationBarHidden = self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden ?? false
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = isNavigationBarHidden
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    fileprivate func loadStops(parameters:[AnyHashable:Any]){
        WSApi.sharedManager.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
        WSApi.shared.getStops(sessionManager: WSApi.sharedManager, parameters: parameters) {[weak self] (status, responseObject) in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.stops.removeAll()
                if let stops = responseObject as? [Stop]{
                    if !strongSelf.searchBar.text!.isEmpty{
                        strongSelf.stops.append(contentsOf: stops)
                    }
                }
                strongSelf.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func closeViewController(){
        if let navigationController = self.navigationController{
            navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
        }else{
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle{
        return .lightContent
    }

    override var preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation: UIStatusBarAnimation{
        return .none
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool{
        return false
    }

}

extension StopSearchViewController :UITableViewDataSource{

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return stops.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: StopSearchCell.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! StopSearchCell
        let stop = stops[indexPath.row]
        cell.configureCell(stop: stop)
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 20
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let attrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 14)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.lightGray]
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"powered by ", attributes:attrs)
        let bAttrs = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 15)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.darkGray]
        let boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"Change Transit", attributes:bAttrs)
        attributedString.append(boldString)
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 44)
        let label = UILabel(frame: frame)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.attributedText = attributedString
        return label
    }


}

extension StopSearchViewController :UITableViewDelegate{

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let stop = stops[indexPath.row]
        self.delegate?.viewController(self, didAutocompleteWith: stop)
       // self.closeViewController()
    }

}

extension StopSearchViewController :UISearchBarDelegate{


    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
//        guard !searchText.isEmpty else {
//            WSApi.sharedManager.operationQueue.cancelAllOperations()
//            self.stops.removeAll()
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
//            return
//        }
        let parameters = ["data_set_id":WSApi.shared.currentContextId ?? "","search_text": searchText]
        self.loadStops(parameters: parameters)
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.delegate?.autocompleteWasCancelled(self)
       // self.closeViewController()
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, Have any sample about my situation?

Comment: I have updated my answer. See the loadStops function in ViewController. This is working code. It works smooth like google places API GMSAutocompleteViewController